# How do I repeat watermark when generate pdf using rotativa?

Tags: rotativa

I am generating pdf using rotativa and in that I need watermark in each page.
I have applied header and footer with custom switches with seperate html.

Answer (score 0):

I solved by following way

```
    <style type="text/css">
        .watermark {
            background-image: url(../../Resources/Watermark/Archived.png);
            background-repeat: repeat;
            background-size: 600px 300px;
        }
    </style>
```

But there is a condition, if you are using rotativa to generate pdf which is you cant put  tag outside body in the  element of out side of .
You must have to put it in the  tag only. Otherwise it wont work.